# How to create text box as shown in the Figure?

Tags: tables, text, text-decorations

How to create a text box as shown in the Figure?
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do that in a one column text like that, it's not readable. It may be ok in a two column text, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX is not really designed to allow that, so it will be tricky. Anyway,
there is a package --- called [`cutwin`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cutwin?lang=en) --- on CTAN, which in the second page of the documentation has:

[image]

Anyway --- the best answer, personally, would be *don't do it*. In the text you cite (and in the above figure I posted) I never know how to "flow" the two semicolumns --- should I read horizontally across the gap or vertically as in a 2-columns document?

Comment: Very very nice. You have my upvoted :-)